# Unable to track changes of deleted and modified mail folders using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

am using graph api to synchronize user's mails and mail folders to the application. Earlier the application uses EWS for synchronization. So when the scheduler runs, the console application will fetch the data using EWS and save it to the database. When using EWS, the code tracks the changes based on changetype like this

```
ChangeCollection\<FolderChange\> fcc = service.ExchangeService.SyncFolderHierarchy(GetFolderId("MsgFolderRoot"), PropertySet.IdOnly, service.EmailRootSyncState);

foreach (FolderChange fc in fcc)
{
switch (fc.ChangeType)
{
case ChangeType.Create:
break;
case ChangeType.Delete:
break;
case ChangeType.Update:
break
}
}
```

So now, using graph api, am trying to retrieve the deleted and renamed (updated) folders like this

Full code goes here...

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var tenantId = "some tenantId";
    var clientId = "some clientid";
    var clientSecret = "some client secret";
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default;

    var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId,
        clientId,
        clientSecret,
        new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });

    GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(credentials);
    var users = await _graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();

    
    string FolderQueryODataDeltaLink = "previous delta token;

    var folderqueryOptions = new List<Option> { };
    if (FolderQueryODataDeltaLink != "")
    {
        folderqueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$deltatoken", FolderQueryODataDeltaLink));
        folderqueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("changeType", "deleted"));
    }

    var folders = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userid]
                            .MailFolders
                            .Delta()
                            .Request(folderqueryOptions)
                            .GetAsync();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But i get all the changed ones (Both deleted folders and renamed folders). Even if i give the changetype as "created", it brings the same result. I think, the changetype parameter is not considered at all.

I also tried without giving the deltatoken query parameter and just sending the changetype. It doesn't work.

What am i doing wrong ?

Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I test in my side and I found with your code, we could have a graph api request with url like screenshot below which doesn't contain `?changeType=deleted` in it.

[image]

So I think we might need to manually manage the url as the workaround like what I did and you can see we could get a correct url. I test the url in Graph Explorer. If the changeType was set to `created` it would have a list of values.

[image]

My code snippet.

```
 var folderqueryOptions = new List<Option> { };
            folderqueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("changeType", "deleted"));
 var folders = graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Delta().Request(folderqueryOptions).RequestUrl;

 var url = graphClient.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.Delta().AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("?changeType=deleted");
 var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(scopes);
 var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;
```

Comment: here what is scopes?

Comment: I test in graph explorer so it uses delegated permission and so I could use `/me`. You used application permission, so the scope for your should be `var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };` And you should add and consent `Application Mail.ReadBasic.All , Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite` API permissions in Azure AD.